# Can't get PHP array to get into CSV via fputcsv()

Tags: php, arrays, csv, fputcsv, array-key

I have an `$events` array that looks like

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [4fe8a21c6f05d60023009d96] => any authentication
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [4fe8a21c6f05d60023009d96] => any authentication
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [4fe8a21c6f05d60023009d96] => any authentication
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [4fe8a21c6f05d60023009d96] => any authentication
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [4fe8a21c6f05d60023009d96] => any authentication
        )
```

And I am using the below code to try and put the user_id and the words "any authentication" each line of the CSV. However, using my code, I see the below (instead of `"4fe8a21c6f05d60023009d96 " "any authentication"`) :

```
"User_ID    "   "   Event"
    "Array  "   "   Array"
    "Array  "   "   Array"
    "Array  "   "   Array"
    "Array  "   "   Array"
    "Array  "   "   Array"
    "Array  "   "   Array"
    "Array  "   "   Array"
    "Array  "   "   Array"
    "Array  "   "   Array"
    "Array  "   "   Array"
    "Array  "   "   Array"
    "Array  "   "   Array"
    "Array  "   "   Array"
    "Array  "   "   Array"
```

My code is:

```
$fp = fopen('events.csv', 'w');
$header = array('User_ID',",",'Event');
fputcsv ($fp, $header, "\t");

foreach ($events as $event) {
    $line = array(array_keys($event),',',$event);
    fputcsv($fp, $line,"\t");
}

fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for your array, try below solution:

```
<?php
$events = array
(
    '0' => array
    (
        '4fe8a21c6f05d60023009d96' => 'any authentication'
    ),

    '1' => array
    (
        '4fe8a21c6f05d60023009d96' => 'any authentication'
    ),

    '2' => array
    (
        '4fe8a21c6f05d60023009d96' => 'any authentication'
    ),

    '3' => array
    (
        '4fe8a21c6f05d60023009d96' => 'any authentication'
    ),

    '4' => array
    (
        '4fe8a21c6f05d60023009d96' => 'any authentication'
    )
);


$fp = fopen('events.csv', 'w+');
$header = array('User_ID',",",'Event');
fputcsv ($fp, $header, "\t");

foreach ($events as $event) {

    $line = array(key($event),',',$event[key($event)]);
    fputcsv($fp, $line,"\t");
}

fclose($fp);
```

for more detail on `fputcsv` have a look at [PHP: fputcsv - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)